# Using SDL with Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: sdl-2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using XMing I was able to run simple graphical applications on WSL such as gvim. Trying to run SDL2 applications doesn't work however. (SDL is unable to create the window). Is there a way to use SDL2 on WSL?

Comment: I do have the same issue and get a `BadRequest` error

Answer (score 4):

I use [vcxsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) with WSL2 to run my SDL2 application. XMing worked for me on WSL1, but not WSL2. I have to uncheck native opengl and check disable access controls to get it to work. In WSL1 I had to `export DISPLAY=:0` but in WSL2 I use `export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0` for the DISPLAY environment variable.